# Find the sum of least common multiples of all subsets of a given set

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, dynamic-programming, primes, prime-factoring

**Given:** set `A = {a0, a1, ..., aN-1}` (`1 ≤ N ≤ 100`), with `2 ≤ ai ≤ 500`.

**Asked:** Find the sum of all least common multiples (LCM) of all subsets of `A` of size at least 2.

The LCM of a set`B = {b0, b1, ..., bk-1}` is defined as the minimum integer `Bmin` such that `bi | Bmin`, for all `0 ≤ i < k`.

**Example:**

Let `N = 3` and `A = {2, 6, 7}`, then:

```
LCM({2, 6})      =    6
LCM({2, 7})      =   14
LCM({6, 7})      =   42
LCM({2, 6, 7})   =   42
----------------------- +
answer              104
```

The naive approach would be to simply calculate the LCM for all `O(2N)` subsets, which is not feasible for reasonably large `N`.

---

**Solution sketch:**

The problem is obtained from a competition<sup>*</sup>, which also provided a [solution sketch](http://acm-icpc.coe.psu.ac.th/contest-problem/solution-sketch-UltimateDevice.pdf). This is where my problem comes in: I do not understand the hinted approach.

The solution reads (modulo some small fixed grammar issues):

> The solution is a bit tricky. If we observe carefully we see that the integers are between `2` and `500`. So, if we prime factorize the numbers, we get the following maximum powers:

```
 2 8  
 3 5
 5 3
 7 3
11 2
13 2
17 2
19 2
```

> Other than this, all primes have power 1. So, we can easily calculate all possible states, using these integers, leaving `9 * 6 * 4 * 4 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3` states, which is nearly `70000`.  For other integers we can make a dp like the following:  `dp[70000][i]`,  where `i` can be `0` to `100`. However, as `dp[i]` is dependent on `dp[i-1]`, so `dp[70000][2]` is  enough.  This leaves the complexity to `n * 70000` which is feasible.

I have the following concrete questions:

- What is meant by these states?
- Does `dp` stand for dynamic programming and if so, what recurrence relation is being solved?
- How is `dp[i]` computed from `dp[i-1]`?
- Why do the big primes not contribute to the number of states? Each of them occurs either `0` or `1` times. Should the number of states not be multiplied by `2` for each of these primes (leading to a non-feasible state space again)?

<sub><sup>*</sup>The original problem description can be found from [this source](http://acm-icpc.coe.psu.ac.th/contest-problem/contest-acm-asia-hy-2012-final.pdf) (problem F). This question is a simplified version of that description.</sub>

Comment: @PhamTrung what "state" means, what dp[state][i] means, and how to do translation dp[f(state)][i] = g( dp[state][i-1] )

Comment: @MasterMind I feel your frustration with this problem, since it has also been stuck on my mind ever since I read your question :) I tried to rephrase the question a bit in order to (hopefully) attract more answers. I think I stayed as close as possible to the core of your original question, but could you please verify this?

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele Thank you so much, you literally understand me fully. The modification you did is just amazing, the questions you asked are core and the heart of the problem. One more time, thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site for asking people to do your homework...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Discussion

After reading the actual contest description ([page 10 or 11](http://acm-icpc.coe.psu.ac.th/contest-problem/contest-acm-asia-hy-2012-final.pdf)) and the solution sketch, I have to conclude the author of the solution sketch is quite imprecise in their writing.

The high level problem is to calculate an expected lifetime if components are chosen randomly by fair coin toss. This is what's leading to computing the LCM of all subsets -- all subsets effectively represent the sample space. You could end up with any possible set of components. The failure time for the device is based on the LCM of the set. The expected lifetime is therefore the average of the LCM of all sets.

Note that this ought to include the LCM of sets with only one item (in which case we'd assume the LCM to be the element itself). The solution sketch seems to sabotage, perhaps because they handled it in a less elegant manner.

### What is meant by these states?

The sketch author only uses the word *state* twice, but apparently manages to switch meanings. In the first use of the word *state* it appears they're talking about a possible selection of components. In the second use they're likely talking about possible failure times. They could be muddling this terminology because their dynamic programming solution initializes values from one use of the word and the recurrence relation stems from the other.

### Does dp stand for dynamic programming?

I would say either it does or it's a coincidence as the solution sketch seems to heavily imply dynamic programming.

### If so, what recurrence relation is being solved? How is dp[i] computed from dp[i-1]?

All I can think is that in their solution, *state* `i` represents a time to failure , `T(i)`, with the number of times this time to failure has been counted, `dp[i]`. The resulting sum would be to sum all `dp[i] * T(i)`.

`dp[i][0]` would then be the failure times counted for only the first component. `dp[i][1]` would  then be the failure times counted for the first and second component. `dp[i][2]` would be for the first, second, and third. Etc..

Initialize `dp[i][0]` with zeroes except for `dp[T(c)][0]` (where `c` is the first component considered) which should be 1 (since this component's failure time has been counted once so far).

To populate `dp[i][n]` from `dp[i][n-1]` for each component `c`:

- For each `i`, copy `dp[i][n-1]` into `dp[i][n]`.
- Add 1 to `dp[T(c)][n]`.
- For each `i`, add `dp[i][n-1]` to `dp[LCM(T(i), T(c))][n]`.

What is this doing? Suppose you knew that you had a time to failure of `j`, but you added a component with a time to failure of `k`. Regardless of what components you had before, your new time to fail is `LCM(j, k)`. This follows from the fact that for two sets `A` and `B`, `LCM(A union B} = LCM(LCM(A), LCM(B))`.

Similarly, if we're considering a time to failure of `T(i)` and our new component's time to failure of `T(c)`, the resultant time to failure is `LCM(T(i), T(c))`. Note that we recorded this time to failure for `dp[i][n-1]` configurations, so we should record that many new times to failure once the new component is introduced.

### Why do the big primes not contribute to the number of states?

> Each of them occurs either 0 or 1 times. Should the number of states not be multiplied by 2 for each of these primes (leading to a non-feasible state space again)?

You're right, of course. However, the solution sketch states that numbers with large primes are handled in another (unspecified) fashion.

What would happen if we did include them? The number of *states* we would need to represent would explode into an impractical number. Hence the author accounts for such numbers differently. Note that if a number less than or equal to 500 includes a prime larger than 19 the other factors multiply to 21 or less. This makes such numbers amenable for brute forcing, no tables necessary.

Comment: I think this answers the concrete questions exactly. I found the part on the recurrence relation somewhat hard to follow (I'm not sure if the context you added makes it simpler than it would have been when you'd just solve the abstract problem or not), but it seems correct.

Comment: Admittedly, I struggled very much to be consistent with the sketch author's wording -- it sounds like the author had a certain pattern in their head that they were using terminology from, even though it didn't match the problem at hand. So I think you're likely right -- I ended up with some of the worst of both worlds -- somewhat incorrect terminology and an esoteric way to solve the problem. Thank you for bringing that to light -- it shall help me improve future answers.

Answer (score 3):

The first part of the editorial seems useful, but the second part is rather vague (and perhaps unhelpful; I'd rather finish this answer than figure it out).

Let's suppose for the moment that the input consists of pairwise distinct primes, e.g., 2, 3, 5, and 7. Then the answer (for summing all sets, where the LCM of 0 integers is 1) is

```
(1 + 2) (1 + 3) (1 + 5) (1 + 7),
```

because the LCM of a subset is exactly equal to the product here, so just multiply it out.

Let's relax the restriction that the primes be pairwise distinct. If we have an input like 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, and 5, then the multiplication looks like

```
(1 + (2^2 - 1) 2) (1 + (2^3 - 1) 3) (1 + (2^1 - 1) 5),
```

because 2 appears with multiplicity 2, and 3 appears with multiplicity 3, and 5 appears with multiplicity 1. With respect to, e.g., just the set of 3s, there are `2^3 - 1` ways to choose a subset that includes a 3, and `1` way to choose the empty set.

Call a prime *small* if it's 19 or less and *large* otherwise. Note that integers 500 or less are divisible by at most one large prime (with multiplicity). The small primes are more problematic. What we're going to do is to compute, for each possible small portion of the prime factorization of the LCM (i.e., one of the ~70,000 states), the sum of LCMs for the problem derived by discarding the integers that could not divide such an LCM and leaving only the large prime factor (or 1) for the other integers.

For example, if the input is 2, 30, 41, 46, and 51, and the state is 2, then we retain 2 as 1, discard 30 (= 2 * 3 * 5; 3 and 5 are small), retain 41 as 41 (41 is large), retain 46 as 23 (= 2 * 23; 23 is large), and discard 51 (= 3 * 17; 3 and 17 are small). Now, we compute the sum of LCMs using the previously described technique. Use [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to get rid of the subsets whose LCM whose small portion properly divides the state instead of being exactly equal. Maybe I'll work a complete example later.

Comment: fyi: it seems, that OP asks specifically about the second part... If you do not understand something it does not automatically mean that it is *unhelpful*.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak Less politely, I think it's wrong, but it's so vague that it's arguably not even wrong.

Comment: It would still be helpful if you'd add more specifically how to use inclusion-exclusion in this situation, but this answer gave many useful pointers.

Answer (score 0):

`What is meant by these states?`

I think here, states refer to if the number is in set B = {b0, b1, ..., bk-1} of LCMs of set A.

`Does dp stand for dynamic programming and if so, what recurrence relation is being solved?`

dp in the solution sketch stands for dynamic programming, I believe.

`How is dp[i] computed from dp[i-1]?`

It's feasible that we can figure out the state of next group of LCMs from previous states. So, we only need array of 2, and toggle back and forth.

`Why do the big primes not contribute to the number of states? Each of them occurs either 0 or 1 times. Should the number of states not be multiplied by 2 for each of these primes (leading to a non-feasible state space again)?`

We can use Prime Factorization and exponents only to present the number.

Here is one example.

6 = (2^1)(3^1)(5^0) -> state "1 1 0" to represent 6
18 = (2^1)(3^2)(5^0) -> state "1 2 0" to represent 18

Here is how we can get LMC of 6 and 18 using Prime Factorization

LCM (6,18) = (2^(max(1,1)) (3^ (max(1,2)) (5^max(0,0)) = (2^1)(3^2)(5^0) = 18

2^9 > 500, 3^6 > 500, 5^4 > 500, 7^4>500, 11^3 > 500, 13^3 > 500, 17^3 > 500, 19^3 > 500

we can use only count of exponents of prime number 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19 to represent the LCMs in the set B = {b0, b1, ..., bk-1} 
for the given set A = {a0, a1, ..., aN-1} (1 ≤ N ≤ 100), with 2 ≤ ai ≤ 500.

9 * 6 * 4 * 4 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 <= 70000, so we only need two of dp[9][6][4][4][3][3][3][3] to keep tracks of all LCMs' states. So, dp[70000][2] is enough.

I put together a small C++ program to illustrate how we can get sum of LCMs of the given set A = {a0, a1, ..., aN-1} (1 ≤ N ≤ 100), with 2 ≤ ai ≤ 500. In the solution sketch, we need to loop through 70000 max possible of LCMs.

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    int remainder = 0;
    do {
        remainder = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = remainder;
    } while (b != 0);
    return a;
}

int lcm(int a, int b) {
    if (a == 0 || b == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (a * b) / gcd(a, b);
}


int sum_of_lcm(int A[], int N) {

    // get the max LCM from the array
    int max = A[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        max = lcm(max, A[i]);
    }
    max++;

    //
    int dp[max][2];
    memset(dp, 0, sizeof(dp));
    int pri = 0;
    int cur = 1;

    // loop through n x 70000
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int v = 1; v < max; v++) {
            int x = A[i];
            if (dp[v][pri] > 0) {
                x = lcm(A[i], v);
                dp[v][cur] = (dp[v][cur] == 0) ? dp[v][pri] : dp[v][cur];
                if ( x % A[i] != 0 ) {
                    dp[x][cur] += dp[v][pri] + dp[A[i]][pri];
                } else {
                    dp[x][cur] += ( x==v ) ? ( dp[v][pri] + dp[v][pri] ) : ( dp[v][pri] ) ;
                }
            }
        }
        dp[A[i]][cur]++;
        pri = cur;
        cur = (pri + 1) % 2;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        dp[A[i]][pri] -= 1;
    }
    long total = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
        if (dp[j][pri] > 0) {
            total += dp[j][pri] * j;
        }
    }
    cout << "total:" << total << endl;

    return total;
}



int test() {
    int a[] = {2, 6, 7 };
    int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    int total = sum_of_lcm(a, n);
    return 0;
}

Output
total:104
```

Comment: Try running your example code with input `[2^8, 3^5, ..., 491, 499]`. The size of array `A` gets a bit above 70000 then...

Comment: This is an illustration of DP for calculate of sum of LCMs, an idea.

Answer (score -2):

The states are one more than the powers of primes.  You have numbers up to 2^8, so the power of 2 is in [0..8], which is 9 states.  Similarly for the other states.

"dp" could well stand for dynamic programming, I'm not sure.

The recurrence relation is the heart of the problem, so you will learn more by solving it yourself.  Start with some small, simple examples.

For the large primes, try solving a reduced problem without using them (or their equivalents) and then add them back in to see their effect on the final result.

Comment: I feel like this answer explains everything but the difficult part.  What is the dynamic programming aspect of the suggested solution?

Comment: @Teepeemm: Exactly.  As I said, "you will learn more by solving it yourself."

Comment: But the only thing your answer has added is to make it explicit that the `9 * 6 * 4 * 4 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3` comes from the powers of the primes.  Other than that (obvious?) fact, this answer adds nothing.

Comment: @Teepeemm: Read it again, "Start with some small, simple examples."

Comment: I totally agree with you that figuring out for yourself is the best way to learn. But what makes you think the OP didn't try any small, simple examples? As it currently stands, this is no answer to the question, merely a comment.